# Javascript JSON unknown behavior

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to set the value of a JSON object property, however when I run `Object.property = value` the entire JSON object is replaced with the string `229,`.

In the following code block:

```
for(var i=0; i<config["profiles"].length; i++){
    profile = config["profiles"][i];
    out = {
      "name":profile["name"],
      "version":profile["version"].replace(/_/g, "."),
      "mods":null,
      "saves":null
    }
    console.log(out)
    out.mods = getMods(profile);
    console.log(out)
    console.log(getSaves(profile))
    out.saves = getSaves(profile);
    console.log(out)
    profiles.push(out);
}
return profiles;
```

The first 2 `console.log(out)` calls return a proper JSON object as expected.

The `console.log(getSaves(profile))` prints the following:

```
[ { name: 'Hard Career ',
    mode: 'CAREER',
    funds: '275,520',
    science: '229',
    reputation: '721',
    flights: '20' },
  { name: 'Sandbox ',
    mode: 'SANDBOX',
    funds: 0,
    science: 0,
    reputation: 0,
    flights: '12' } ]
```

However, the print directly after `out.saves = getSaves(profile)` prints the following: `229,`.

To make things even more complicated, this only occurs on one item in the `config["profiles"]` array.

If anyone has possible solutions to the problem, I would love to hear them. If you need more information about the code, I'll see what I can do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `console.log` is a live view of objects. Try using `console.log(JSON.stringify(out))` so you're seeing the actual snapshots

Comment: Also you should always declare variables like `let out = `

Comment: @MarkMeyer that's probably the problem

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: You give a reference to the processed `profile` to the functions `getMods` and `getSaves`, however, you do not provide the code of those. I'm afraid there is nobody from the glass ball business online here.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thanks, that fixed it. If you set that as an answer I would be happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare your variables with something like `let profile =`

If you don't do this `profile` and `out` will be global variables, which means each time through your `for` loop you are reassigning a single shared global variable. If you have other code that is also doing this it can very difficult to keep track of. Changing your code to:

```
let profile = config["profiles"][i];
let out = {
  "name":profile["name"],
  "version":profile["version"].replace(/_/g, "."),
  "mods":null,
  "saves":null
}
```

should help.